# How to prevent a token transfer in smart contract?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, erc20

Is there any way to prevent token transfer from address A to address B in a smart contract? Let's say it needs some sort of approval from smart contract owner. Assuming it is not ERC-20 token.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to implement such a restriction in your code logic.

For example, you could create a mapping with addresses that only the smart contract owner can add entries to. (Using an [onlyOwner modifier](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.10/contracts.html#function-modifiers)). Then implement a require function that only permits the transfer if the address is in the mapping.

```
mapping (address=>bool) addr_mapping;

function transferToken(address sender, address receiver) public{
    require(addr_mapping[sender] == true, "Sender not in mapping");
    require(addr_mapping[receiver] == true, "Receiver not in mapping");
    ...
}

function addToMapping(address addr) onlyOwner {
    ...
}
```

PS. Not sure if the boolean comparison is possible, but you can create your own flag.